# Python3 - EC2 - smtplib - OVH : error "[Errno 104] Connection reset by peer"

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, smtplib, ovh

Using smtplib in python3 I am facing an issue using it on an ec2 machine of AWS

I am using the folowing function :

```
def ovh_send_email(sender_name, sender_address, recipient_addresses, subject, body_text, body_html, attachments = []):

mail_username = u'xxx@xxx.xx'
mail_password = u'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
mail_smtp_server = "ssl0.ovh.net"
mail_smtp_port = 465

session = smtplib.SMTP_SSL(mail_smtp_server, mail_smtp_port) #Initiate connection to the server
session.set_debuglevel(1)

session.ehlo() #Start encrypting everything you're sending to the server
session.login(mail_username, mail_password) #Define the recipient of the email

msg = MIMEMultipart('mixed')
msg['Subject'] = subject
msg['From'] = sender_name + " <" + sender_address + ">"
msg['To'] = ", ".join(recipient_addresses)

html = body_html

part2 = MIMEText(body_html, 'html', 'utf-8')


for attachment_name in attachments:
    attachment = MIMEApplication(attachments[attachment_name])
    attachment.add_header("Content-Disposition", "attachment", filename=attachment_name)
    msg.attach(attachment)


msg.attach(part2)


session.sendmail(mail_username, recipient_addresses, msg.as_string())#Close the connection to the SMTP server 
session.quit()
```

What I get is

```
Exception Type: ConnectionResetError at /contact-email
Exception Value: [[Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
```

I have also tryed with the 587 port to send mail with no ssh but the problem remains

What is strange is that it doss not occure on another EC2 when I run the ovh_send_email function directly from the terminal

once I get this in terminal but I never saw it again whet I tryed some more time ...

```
ovh_send_email(sender_name, sender_address, recipient_addresses, subject, body_text, body_html)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 8, in ovh_send_email
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/smtplib.py", line 1021, in __init__
    source_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/smtplib.py", line 251, in __init__
    (code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/smtplib.py", line 335, in connect
    self.sock = self._get_socket(host, port, self.timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/smtplib.py", line 1029, in _get_socket
    server_hostname=self._host)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/ssl.py", line 385, in wrap_socket
    _context=self)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/ssl.py", line 760, in __init__
    self.do_handshake()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/ssl.py", line 996, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/ssl.py", line 641, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ConnectionResetError: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
```

Any idea to help ?
THX !!!

Answer (score 0):

You are getting blocked by your mail provider because smtplib doesn't have any concrete super secure certificate which is necessary to send email via gmail or other mail engines. The problem is not on your code or the port...

You can do the following:

- Go to your mail settings
- Go to security settings of your mail
- Enable access of your email by less secure apps

And you should be good to go!

Answer (score 0):

I thought about that and will dig into this idea

What seems strange to me is that
• sometime i get the [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
• and sometime I dont ... I mean it works

example :

```
first try --> [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
second try -- > OK
third try -- > OK
4th try --> [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
5th try -- > OK
```

and so on !

Answer (score 0):

Encoding special characters was causing the error in my case. I got rid of them and of: .encode('utf-8') on my sendmail command